# Can a combo box be used to control a list box?

Tags: ms-access-2013

Can a combo box be used to set the criteria for a list box?  I have a combo box, State, that is the main criteria selection for many of the controls on the form that reside in subforms.  I can get those controls to work if they are combo boxes or text boxes, but not in a list box.  What I need to do is have the user select 1 of 3 states, then based on that selection, only certain habitats will appear in a list box.  I am VERY green and really don't understand VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Except if the Listbox is set to *multiselect*, it behaves like a Combobox, thus your secret code working with a Combobox will work with a Listbox as well.

Comment: It is set to multiselect, which is the only reason I have a list box.  It is imperative that there be more than one selection available

Comment: OK, but if you neither expose your secret code nor phrase your problem we don't have much to work with.